# Not able to load keras model on nodejs platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

I am trying to create a simple web app that contains my trained model on mnist dataset and it predicts the number that is drawn on the canvas but I am not able to load the model, I have converted the model into json format .
My directory for the project is like this :

```
./Project 
    local-server/
      -server.js
    static/
       model/
         -model.json
       predict-with-tfjs.html
       predict.js
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const tf=require('@tensorflow/tfjs')

app.use(express.static("../static"));

app.set("view engine", "html");
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'predict-with-tfjs.html')
});

app.get("/dog", (req, res) => res.send("This is a dog page"));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:3000`));
```

**predict.js**

```
let model;
(async function () {
    model = await tf.loadModel("http://localhost:3000/predict-with-tfjs.html/model/model.json");
    console.log(model)
})();
console.log(model)
```

The model is not able to load and I have searched every possible solution.

Comment: What is the error you have ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `__dirname` and `path.join`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../static')));
```

Answer (score 0):

1.require '@tensorflow/tfjs-node' -> require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

2. if it still doesnt work, you can try 'file://' protocol
3. assuming you created model.json using tensorflowjs_converter , Use tf.loadGraphModel('file://.....')

Hope it helps.